# Symfony 4 - How to avoid rendering the form if database lookup fails?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a form which loads based on a lookup from the database of a id value from a get request.

```
$Id = $request->query->get('id');

if (!empty($Id) && $Id != 'add') {
    $search = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Clients::class)
        ->find($Id);

    if (is_null($search))
        $this->addFlash('danger', 'Invalid Client');
    else
        $form = $this->createForm(ClientViewType::class,$search);
}
else {
    $form = $this->createForm(ClientViewType::class);
}
```

You can see I'm adding a flashbag message of 'invalid client', but the problem is the form will still show.  Is there some way to not show the form?  Basically I just want the flashbag message to display and that's it.

I tried some things - i.e. setting $form to null, just returning the page, without the form, etc. but that just forces other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed set $form to null when you have an invalid client. Then in your twig you could have a conditional rendering like this:

```
{% if form is not null %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% else %}
    {% for message in app.flashes('danger') %}
        <div class="flash-notice">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
if (is_null($search)) {
    $this->addFlash('danger', 'Invalid Client');
    return $this->render("...", [
       "form" => null
        ...
    ]);
}
```

and then in twig file make following if condition:

```
{% if form is not null %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
         {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the not famous `else` clause with the `for`condition

```
{% for message in app.flashes('danger') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% else %}
   {# your form #}
{% endfor %}
```

see [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-else-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Try using instanceof instead.

```
if ($search instanceof Clients) {...}
```

This helped me to overcome some of those problems.

I agree with the other answers, especially iiirxs'.